# Skype launcher icon not working

Tags: unity, launcher, skype

I had to do a fresh install of my OSs, and after downloading all the updates and going up to 12.10 (The disk I had was 12.04), I installed Skype, and it works fine... from the terminal, that is.  I can run it fine from there, but the icon launcher does not work.  It flashes a little like it's loading, but then nothing happens.  I don't know what else to say, it's simple inconvenience nuance, but I wouldn't mind fixing it.

/usr/share/app-install/desktop/skype.desktop:

```
[Desktop Entry]
X-AppInstall-Package=skype
X-AppInstall-Proprietary=true
X-AppInstall-Channel=quantal-partner
X-AppInstall-LicenseUri=/usr/share/app-install/channels/quantal-partner.eula
Name=Skype
Comment=Skype Internet Telephony
Exec=skype-wrapper
Icon=skype.png
Terminal=0
Type=Application
Encoding=UTF-8
Categories=Network;Application;
```

/usr/share/applications/skype.desktop:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Skype
Comment=Skype Internet Telephony
Exec=skype %U
Icon=skype.png
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Encoding=UTF-8
Categories=Network;Application;
MimeType=x-scheme-handler/skype;
X-KDE-Protocols=skype
```

Comment: Please go to `/usr/share/app-install/desktop/skype.desktop` and add the contents of the file in your question.

Comment: It has been done.

Comment: and the contents of `/usr/share/applications/skype.desktop`?

Comment: I added it to the post.

Comment: Both files look fine. Try launching Skype through the icon then in a terminal type `dmesg | tail` and see if there are any error messages.

Comment: There is nothing.  I tried it a couple times.

Comment: How do you launch it through terminal, what command do you use? `skype-wrapper` or `skype` ?

Comment: I use simply `skype`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was experiencing the same thing. The problem is that the `Exec=skype-wrapper` line in the `/usr/share/app-install/desktop/skype.desktop` file is wrong. The executable `skype-wrapper` doesn't exist. If you change that line to `Exec=skype` then it will work.

I've opened https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/app-install-data-partner/+bug/1194322 to track the bug.